# How to vertically center div relative to flexbox grandparent?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

Given a div with display flexbox `.wrapper` (run and see snippet below) and a deeply nested div `.text-container`, how can I center the deeply nested div relative to the `.wrapper` and not relative to its parent `.variable-height`?

In the snippet below there are two columns with equal height and I want the text, which is placed in a variable height div inside each column, to be at the same level. I have set the display of the variable height div also to `flexbox`, so logically the text is centered, relative to it and not to the grandparent `.wrapper`, which is not what I want.

The only solution I came up with is to set `position: relative;` on `.wrapper` and on `.text-container`:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

However, I am not sure, if it's a good idea to mix flexbox and absolute/relative positioning.

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper .fixed-height {
  background-color: orange;
  min-height: 30px;
}

.wrapper .second {
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 30px;
}

.wrapper .variable-height {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper .variable-height .text-container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="fixed-height"></div>
  <div class="fixed-height second"></div>
  <div class="variable-height">
    <div class="text-container">
      <div class="title">Title</div>
      <div class="subtitle">Subtitle</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fixed-height"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="fixed-height"></div>
  <div class="variable-height">
    <div class="text-container">
      <div class="title">Title</div>
      <div class="subtitle">Subtitle</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fixed-height"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I also think that  is the only solution in this case https://jsfiddle.net/hzxwu1qh/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I am not sure, if it's a good idea to mix flexbox and absolute/relative positioning.

Well, it depends on what sort of behavior is acceptable to you.

When you absolutely position an element, you remove it from the document flow.

So, in this case, `.wrapper` and its flex items don't know that `.text-container` exists. If there's any flexibility to the container or items, they will overlap with `.text-container`. See this illustration:

[**Centering: Absolute Positioning vs Flexbox**](https://jsfiddle.net/e9qpye00/) (re-size the window to see the difference)

Again, if the overlapping is acceptable to you, then absolute positioning is fine.

---

In terms of the flexbox specification, there's nothing wrong with mixing absolute / relative positioning with flex properties. The spec has a section on this subject:

> [**4.1. Absolutely-Positioned Flex Children**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items)
>
> An absolutely-positioned child of a flex container does not participate in flex layout. However, it does participate in the reordering step (see `order`), which has an effect in their painting order.
>
> The static position of an absolutely-positioned child of a flex container is determined such that the child is positioned as if it were the sole flex item in the flex container, assuming both the child and the flex container were fixed-size boxes of their used size.
>
> The effect of this is that if you set, for example, `align-content: center;` on an absolutely-positioned child of a flex container, the child’s static position will center it in the flex container’s cross axis.

Two things to note from the spec:

- Although an absolutely positioned flex item is removed from the document flow (as expected), it still recognizes the `order` property.
- You can still use flex properties to center an absolutely positioned flex item, but only under certain circumstances and *only within the parent container, not the grandparent*.